# What does the Carbine do in A Dark Room and how do I use it?

Tags: a-dark-room

I picked two up at a fallen battlefield but can't seem to work out what they do and how to work them.

[image]

Comment: From what I can gather, a Carbine is a type of weapon.  It requires 1 energy cell to use.  From [the Wiki](http://adarkroom.wikia.com/wiki/Items_(iOS)), it also states a battery is needed to use it.  I would assume the way you use it is the same as any other weapon in the game, though I have never played it, so I could be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Timmy is correct. Carbine is a ranged weapon.

From the [wiki](http://adarkroom.wikia.com/wiki/Items_(iOS))

> **Carbine**
> type: ranged
> damage: 8
> cooldown: 1 seconds
> use cost: 1 battery
> creation cost: Cannot be created

Batteries are used as ammo for carbine.

> **Battery**
> weight: 0.1
> trade cost: 10 Scales
> production by armourer cost: 1 steel + 1 sulphur (per 10 sec)

Comment: But how do you use it?

Comment: If you carry a carbine and have enough batteries then u can use it like any other weapon with a one second cd.

Comment: How many betteries and where can I find energy cells??

Comment: The use cost was supposed to be one battery and not one cell. Cells are used as ammo for laser rifles. Answer Edited.